# Populate all rows in one cardview

Tags: java, android, xamarin

Is there any way to populate(wrap) all rows into one `CardView`. Not to creating a `CardView` for each row.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFvYG.png)

Here is my xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="98"
   >
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <TextView
        android:text="Description"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="18" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Quantity"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/Quantity"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="20" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Price"
        android:id="@+id/Price"
        android:textSize="20sp"
         android:gravity="right"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Sum"
        android:id="@+id/SumPrice"
        android:textSize="20sp"
       android:gravity="right"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Dis.Price"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:id="@+id/SumDiscountPrice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="20" />

  </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I need to create one cardview for all items. Or if there is also way to manage, in which row cardview will start or finish. 
If you need more details about my activity please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your RecyclerView inside your CardView not the items, this will be your fragment/activity's layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    android:margin="8dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RecyclerView 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do little work on both file, means your `main_file` and your particular item file means `child_file`.

Find your `main_file.xml`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/card_view"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
android:margin="8dp">

<RecyclerView 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

And find your `child_file.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="98">
<TextView
    android:text="Description"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/Name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="18" />
<TextView
    android:text="Quantity"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/Quantity"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="20" />
<TextView
    android:text="Price"
    android:id="@+id/Price"
    android:textSize="20sp"
     android:gravity="right"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="20" />
<TextView
    android:text="Sum"
    android:id="@+id/SumPrice"
    android:textSize="20sp"
   android:gravity="right"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="20" />
<TextView
    android:text="Dis.Price"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:id="@+id/SumDiscountPrice"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="20" />
</LinearLayout>
```